# Android deep linking is not working

Tags: android

```
Android deep linking is not working
===================================
 Android link:-notification://id=notificationid
```

1:-In manifest

```
      <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data
                        android:host="id"
                        android:scheme="notification" />
                </intent-filter>
```

2:-and coding side

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();        
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String string=intent.getAction();
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            Log.d("hello","cgbdsuyfdkv");
        }
```

but its not working please any body can help me !!!!!

Comment: is your code run for first time?

Comment: yes run my code and my url like this (notification://id=notificationid)but can its can not work

Comment: But second time you could not get updated notification id ? right

Comment: yes i can not getting updated value why

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: yes i checked its not working

Comment: have you added any lonchmode in AndroidManifest.xml in your Activtiy

Comment: yes
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="id"
                    android:scheme="notification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Add singleTask Lunch mode and try with onNewIntent() method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply modify your url

```
Android link:-notification://id=notificationid instead of
Android link:-notification://page?id=notificationid  //page is host name
I tried a lot and find out this is working for me.
```

1. manifest code

   ```
              <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

               <data
                   android:host="page"
                   android:scheme="notification" />
           </intent-filter>
   ```

2.java code #get your notification id here

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String string = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        String path = data.getPath();
        String path1 = data.getPath();
        providerUrl = intent.getData().toString();
        UrlQuerySanitizer sanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer();
        sanitizer.setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(true);
        sanitizer.parseUrl(providerUrl);
        String id = sanitizer.getValue("id");
        if (id != null)
            Log.d("notification id", id);
    }
```

Comment: yes i agree 
my Android link:-**notification://id=notificationid** is not correct.
when i change url **notification://hostname?id=notificationid**
its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Add `onNewIntent()` method to your `Activity` and then use intent object which is variable in `OnNewintent()` method , which has updated method.

`onNewIntent()` is meant as entry point for `singleTop` or `singleTask` activities which already run somewhere else in the stack and therefore can't call `onCreate()`. From activities lifecycle point of view it's therefore needed to call `onPause()` before `onNewIntent()`. I suggest you to rewrite your activity to not use these listeners inside of `onNewIntent()`. For example most of the time my `onNewIntent()` methods simply looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
//use this  intent object to get notificationid for second time 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1st step:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="your_uri_scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

2nd step:

```
Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
    String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
    Log.i("MyApp", "Deep link clicked " + uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you Intent Filter is incomplete

```
<!-- To open app using link -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="yourdomain.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/someurlparam">
        </data>
    </intent-filter>
```