# Deep links not working anymore in Android

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking

I've started a new project in Android Studio and added this to my `androidmanifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then I went to Google Chrome and typed in: `http://www.example.com/gizmos`. The App doesn't open. And then tried command line:

```
mac-van-jim:DeeplinkTest jimclermonts$ adb shell am start -n eu.theappfactory.deeplinktest/MainActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=eu.theappfactory.deeplinktest/MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {eu.theappfactory.deeplinktest/MainActivity} does not exist.
```

And this one:

```
mac-van-jim:DeeplinkTest jimclermonts$ adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com" eu.theappfactory
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com/... pkg=eu.theappfactory }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=eu.theappfactory }
```

I've tried these threads:

[Deep Link does not work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713357/deep-link-does-not-work-on-android)

[Android deep linking is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555434/android-deep-linking-is-not-working)

[Deep-linking intent does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808777/deep-linking-intent-does-not-work)

Nothing is working? I can remember this used to work? Maybe it's because of the new Android App Links?

EDIT: I figured out that it doesn't work in Chrome (anymore) but when creating and uploading a webpage, it also doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

    <a href="Click here" target="_blank">http://www.example.com/gizmos</a>

</body>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

To start your app with the provided url you should run this command:

```
adb shell "am start 'http://www.example.com/gizmos'"
```

Also, Chrome is designed to not open your app if you copy/pate the link in the URL search bar.

Comment: You sure about chrome ? If I go on reddit.com it starts the dialog box directly but not working on my websites. The command you provided make the box appears however